# moving files from a subsubfolder to a folder x10000 times

Tags: directory

I have a lot of folders that need organizing that would take weeks to do by hand. I already know that the *.* trick will work, but then I will lose the already organized file structure. What I need is my main folder (let's call it C:\docs) that has hundreds of subfolders (folder a-j), have even more subfolders within the subfolders (which I am calling subsub folders) I don't want to lose the folder structure of folder a-j, but the folders within those folders need to be emptied to their respective subfolders.

```
DOCS
folder a
 sub folder 1
    file 1,2,3,4......
 sub folder 2
    file 5,6,7,8......
 sub folder 3 
    file 9,10,11,12....
folder b
 sub folder 1
    file 1,2,3,4......
 sub folder 2
    file 5,6,7,8......
 sub folder 3 
    file 9,10,11,12....
```

and so on.

INTO

```
DOCS
folder a
   file 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12......
folder b
   file 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12......
```

and so on.

Any help with this would be great. I can't even get the language right to google search my problem, because all I get is the - *.* trick, which again is fine but would take actual weeks to do with the number of folders that need this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure why, but it wont let me write astrix.astrix but, yeah that trick I've done seen it and no, its not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to copy the structure with ROBOCOPY.EXE tool and save it somewhere like C:\Backup\
I would run a command DOS like this:
robocopy c:\docs*.* c:\backup\ /CREATE

This will copy only the structure of subdirectories.

type in a DOS box:
robocopy /?
to get all options